# On VPN, some in-network IP addresses blocked-- only for me

Tags: router, vpn, netmask

I VPN to my office, both from a Linux system with openvpn and a Windows system with WatchGuard. A few days ago, all of the sudden I cannot ping certain IP addresses in the network, while others work fine.

The admin used my credentials from his home, and it works fine. Thus, we cannot even reproduce the problem.

How can I begin to troubleshoot this problem?

Here is the Route Table from the Windows machine.  The IP address that works is 195.168.5.13.  The IP address that does not work is 195.168.5.14.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.4     20
        10.0.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.10.3    276
        10.0.10.3  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.10.3    276
      10.0.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.10.3    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.4    276
      192.168.0.4  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.4    276
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.4    276

      195.168.5.0    255.255.255.0        10.0.10.1        10.0.10.3     20

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.10.3    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.4    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.10.3    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.4    276
===========================================================================
```

Comment: You can begin to give us a little more detail. Basically, whatever you know.
IP addresses in your local LAN, IP addresses assigned by VPN, addresses which can and which can not be pinged, the routing table of your PC while connected to VPN and while disconnected and so on...

Comment: It should be the admin's job to troubleshoot further, just because it works for him doesn't mean your PC can't have it's own problems. Just like xpac said, check your route tables (on windows `print route`) to see if the network traffic is sent to the right gateway (the IPs should all be included in that network range). Depending on that, the admin needs to check further.

Comment: Windows machine local IP address is 192.168.0.4.

Comment: The routing table looks fine so far. Do you have the same problem with both workstations (Linux and Windows)? If yes, I would rather look for the problem on the VPN server side or the remote hosts. If only one of your machines is affected, it's rather a local problem. Also, you might want to install Wireshark to actually see what happens on your network interface and which data is sent and received.

Comment: Ran a `tracert` and found packets would die after the gateway.  So we rebooted the computers on the VPN side and now everything works.  Still puzzled.